# Hive calendar day to Julian date

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, julian-date

I'm trying to convert as the title says a calendar date to a julian date, the way I do it in Teradata is:

```
CAST((TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE-1,'J')) AS INT)
```

I tried with the following:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),1), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'j')
```

but 'j' is not a valid pattern for hive.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I'm not trying to get the Julian date with the format YYYYddd, I am trying to get the julian date in which today 14/02/2018 is 2458164.

**more edit:**
This function in Teradata outputs the Julian Day which is the number of days since 31 December 4713 BC.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: see this link: https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/how-to-convert-julian-date-to-calander-date-in-hive/

Comment: @cricket_007 that is java, I am trying to do it in hive.

Comment: Hive **is Java**

Comment: @anonyXmous Thanks but in teradata that is not the way is formed the julian date, when I run: 
` (TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'J'))`
I got: 2458164, where 2458 is not the actual year.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, sorry, I was not specific, I am trying to use HiveQL.

Comment: I don't think you understood... Read the documentation for HiveQL date functions. It'll specially tell you that SimpleDateFormat format variables are what you use

Comment: As far as I know, Hive has no such function for "days since epoch". The best you could do would be divide seconds since epoch by the seconds in a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fernando; I used this link to compute it: https://quasar.as.utexas.edu/BillInfo/JulianDatesG.html.  Please note that in the website it says (to quote):

> Note that this always gives you a half day extra. That is because the Julian Day begins at noon, Greenwich time. This is convenient for astronomers (who until recently only observed at night), but it is confusing.

```
SELECT 2-CAST(IF(MONTH(date_sub(current_date(),1))<=2, YEAR(date_sub(current_date(),1))-1,YEAR(date_sub(current_date(),1)))/100 AS INT)+CAST(CAST(IF(MONTH(date_sub(current_date(),1))<=2, YEAR(date_sub(current_date(),1))-1,YEAR(date_sub(current_date(),1)))/100 AS INT)/4 AS INT)+DAY(date_sub(current_date(),1))+CAST(365.25*(IF(MONTH(date_sub(current_date(),1))<=2,YEAR(date_sub(current_date(),1))-1, YEAR(date_sub(current_date(),1)))+4716) AS INT)+CAST(30.6001*(IF(MONTH(date_sub(current_date(),1))<=2, MONTH(date_sub(current_date(),1))+12, MONTH(date_sub(current_date(),1)))+1) AS INT)-1524.5;
```

Current date minus one day: Feb 13, 2018
Result:  2458162.5

Also this warning (to quote the site again):

> Warning: This computation is not guaranteed for Gregorian dates prior
>   to 1582, nor for negative Julian Day Numbers.

=========PREVIOUS INCORRECT ANSWER=======

@fernando, please use date_sub function and the format is yyyyDDD. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
Query: select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(current_date, 1),'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyDDD');

Result: 2018044

where Year: 2018 and J: 044
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the format yyyyddd, I want the other julian date, the one in where today is 2458164. I already edited the post.

Comment: @FernandoColínPerusquia; here is my new answer. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: yup; I run it in hive and the result is: OK
_c0
2458211.5
Time taken: 59.537 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Comment: please let me know the error message you are getting

Comment: current_date was not working. I changed it and it worked!
I can't paste here. Is too long for a comment.

Comment: good to know that it works for you. current_date is synonym to unix timestamp but in a different format. do i get an upvote on my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved with the code of @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ. I just make a little change to use from_unixtime and unix_timestamp instead of current_date.

```
ceiling(2
                    -CAST(IF(MONTH(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))<=2, YEAR(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))-1,YEAR(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))/100 AS INT)
                    +CAST(CAST(IF(MONTH(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))<=2, YEAR(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))-1,YEAR(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))/100 AS INT)/4 AS INT)
                    +DAY(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))
                    +CAST(365.25*(IF(MONTH(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))<=2,YEAR(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))-1, YEAR(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))+4716) AS INT)
                    +CAST(30.6001*(IF(MONTH(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))<=2, MONTH(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))+12, MONTH(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/04/2018','dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))+1) AS INT)
                    -1524.5)
```

Also I put a ceiling function to avoid decimals.

Comment: spent 2 hours to compute my answer, yet got less points; life is not fair most of the time :D